# OpenCL with Mac OS X 10.11.1

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-errors, parallel-processing

I'm trying to compile some OpenCL Programms with Code:Blocks but I can't find anywhere how to configure the compiler to run my files.

The same thing with Xcode 7.

How can I make a project that compiles OpenCL files?

I already have Command Line Tool and have found some tutorials online, but they are all for older versions of Xcode.

I currently have OS X 10.11.1 installed.